# Powershell DSC, Output MOF to different folder

Tags: powershell, dsc

Given this simple configuration file:

```
Configuration MyDscConfiguration {

    Node "TEST-PC1" {
        WindowsFeature MyFeatureInstance {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name =  "RSAT"
        }
        WindowsFeature My2ndFeatureInstance {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name = "Bitlocker"
        }
    }
}
MyDscConfiguration
```

When run, the MOF file generated for Node "TEST-PC1", will be placed in a sub-directory named, `MyDscConfiguration`.

I am looking for a way to output the MOF to a custom directory location, e.g. `mofs\MyDscConfiguration\`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your configuration has an `-OutputPath` parameter you can give it.

Configurations are, essentially, functions and work mostly the same way.

You can even use `Get-Help MyDscConfiguration` to see all the parameters it has (you can define your own `param()` block with it too, just like you would for a function).

<kbd>TAB</kbd> completion works too, so that's a quick way to discover the params.